# codeigniter check if uri segment exist in database

Tags: database, codeigniter, controller, uri, segment

I am trying to create dynamic pages without creating new files and getting the data from the database...

so my table will be like:

```
Pages
------
id | page_name | text
1  | about     | about page goes here
2  | contact   | contact page goes here
```

now my question is how can i manage to make `$this->uri->segement(1)` to automatically check if the given page name exist in database?

do i have to create a new controller that will handle all this or?

Comment: Have a look at [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several pages that you want to check, I would recommend having a Pages controller that managers those pages. Something like this

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function view($page_name)
    {
        $this->load->Pages_model();

        if($this->Pages_model->does_exist($page_name))
        {
            // Does exist. Do things.
        } else
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `routes.php`, you route your `about` and  `contact` pages (and whatever others you may have) to the pages controller.

```
$route['about'] = "pages/view/about";
$route['contact'] = "pages/view/contact";
```

Your `Pages_model` will need a simple function that checks if the page name exists in the database.

```
function does_exist($page_name) {

    $this->db->where('name', $page_name); // assuming you have a table with a `name` field
    $query = $this->db->get('pages'); // select from the `pages` table
    return $query->num_rows() > 0; // returns bool

}
```